Extracting multiple strings starting with specific characters from single row
I have a table in which one of the columns has large XML data. I want to extract strings which start with SAP (upper case) (Eg: SAP-PTS-RSK-SEC-A-006-GFC). These strings appear on multiple instances and are always preceded by <form_id> and followed by </form_id>. This is an small extract of the text in the column. I have highlighted the part of that text I was referring to earlier.
No</entity_number><form_value>Form Value</form_value><is_data_limited>FALSE</is_data_limited></headers><entities><entity_number>GPSCAPSA</entity_number><detection_value>Financial Services - Money Services Business</form_value><drills_data><drill_context>***<form_id>SAP-PTS-RSK-SEC-A-006-GFC</form_id>***<alert_date>2023-07-11</alert_date><entity_type_cd>1</entity_type_cd><entity_key>63111179</entity_key><entity_sk>63111149</entity_sk><is_external_party>0</is_external_party><start_date>2023-07-11</start_date><end_date>2023-07-

My expectation is to have a column which lists there strings with a comma in between
SAP-PTS-RSK-SEC-A-006-GFC,
SAP-PTS-FUI-SEC-A-006-SLA,
SAP-VCR-RSK-KGB-A-006-GFC

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

SQL Server has a bunch of XML functions... what have you tried and what did you get stuck on?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

since you did not provided xml structure. here is an example https://dbfiddle.uk/f825FyDU

your data doesn't include  SAP-PTS-FUI-SEC-A-006-SLA,
SAP-VCR-RSK-KGB-A-006-GFC and your xml data has issues

The sample you provide is not clear. Please - for future questions - try to provide working data.
The XML fragment seems to have an opening <detection_value> without the closing tag. If your XML is not valid you are in troubles...
However: If the XML in your table is working/valid XML this is quite simple:
Starting with a working sample extracted from your XML fragment:
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl(YourXml) VALUES
(N'
<drills_data>
  <drill_context>   
    <form_id>SAP-PTS-RSK-SEC-A-006-GFC</form_id>
    <alert_date>2023-07-11</alert_date>
  </drill_context>
</drills_data>
<drills_data>
  <drill_context>
    <form_id>SAP-SomeOtherCode</form_id>
    <alert_date>2023-07-11</alert_date>
  </drill_context>
</drills_data>
<drills_data>
  <drill_context>
    <form_id>Blub-OneWithoutSAP</form_id>
    <alert_date>2023-07-11</alert_date>
  </drill_context>
</drills_data>
');

--The query
SELECT SAP.formId.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('//form_id[substring(text()[1],1,3)="SAP"]') SAP(formId);

The idea in short:

We use CROSS APPLY to use the XML function nodes().
The XQuery performs a deep search (it will find any <form_id>).
It will filter just for entries where the first 3 characters are SAP.
XQuery is case sensitive, this works for upper-case "SAP" only.
In the SELECT we use .value() to read the content.

The result (The third with "Blub" is not returned).
SAP-PTS-RSK-SEC-A-006-GFC
SAP-SomeOtherCode

Hint: If the XML is not XML but a string you can go with this:
SELECT SAP.formId.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(t.YourXml AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('//form_id[substring(text()[1],1,3)="SAP"]') SAP(formId);

Hint2: It is faster and better not to perform a deep search (with //form_id) but to specify the path leading there. But we do not know your actual XML.
